# Crossover NIC2 causing issues with Internet on NIC1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter, crossover

So I am currently using a USB wireless adapter as "NIC 1" and a USB Gigabit RJ45 Adapter as NIC2 for crossover transfers to a second computer. I have already set the metrics to have the wireless connection to have higher priority than the second NIC, but windows would still "use" part of the second NIC which slows/time out webpages. Disabling or unplugging the second NIC would instantly restore the connection/speed of the "internet connection" on NIC1.

If I use the slower on board wireless on my laptop along with the crossover nic, this would not happen. Both of the on board wireless and usb wireless adapter were set to higher priority than the crossover nic (as shown in route print)

**NIC 1 Setup:**

IP: 192.168.1.53

SM: 255.255.255.0

DG: 192.168.1.1

DNS

1.1.1.1

1.0.0.1

**NIC 2 (Crossover) Setup**

IP: 192.168.3.2

SM: 255.255.0.0

Using Windows 10 Pro 1903

any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you start up Wireshark and check what exactly is Windows trying to "use" the second NIC for? Since you don't have a 192.168.3.x gateway configured, it normally shouldn't be used for much. (And NICs don't just automagically get used, they only get used if the routing table says to use them for something specific.)

Answer (score 1):

`route print` does not show priority; it shows route *metric*, which is interpreted as **cost or distance**. Therefore higher metric means *lower* priority, and you should aim for the direct-connection NIC routes to have highest metric, not lowest.